# Why I can't use result of function as a state in useState

Tags: javascript, react-hooks, use-state

I try to use `useState` with an array of objects as a value. Something like this:

```
const [state, setState] = useState(arg)
```

Arg is the result of function which returns an array like this:

```
[{a:1, b:2}, {a:3, b:4}]
```

But when I try to use it, my state is empty and nothing happens. How to use an arg in `useState`?
I see another similar questions, but these solutions doesn't work. Or maybe I don't understand.

```js
//take users list from DB
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  const items = useSelector((state) => state.users.list)

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(funcThatGetUsersList)
  }, [dispatch])
  
//use items for handler
  const [list, setList] = useState([])
  
  function checkboxHandler = (event) => {
    do smth with setList(list)
   }
```

Added a little piece of code

Comment: How do you try to use it? Can you share some more code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cannot use useState directly. Perhaps my solution will help. I passed the value with useEffect. such as

```
useEffect(() => {
if (list)
  setList(yourFunc)
  )
}, [yourFunc])
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use [lazy initial state](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#lazy-initial-state), the function will be evaluated only once.

If it returns different values in subsequent renders, those other values will be ignored.

```
const condition = false
const getArg = () => condition ? arg : []

useState(getArg) // getArg() will be called only once
```